# Fill in DLL import table manually: IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR's Name field stores 0x0000FFFF

Tags: c++, dll, hook, dllimport, portable-executable

My goal is to fill in Dll's import table manually in order to hook internal LoadLibrary calls (when you load library it may load another library inside its DllMain).

Here is my code which fill in Import table recursively for each dll in dependecies hierarchy and it works fine except some dlls (**api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll** in this case).

```cpp
void PEUtility::fillImportTable(HMODULE loadedModule, FillImportFlag flag, std::function<void(HMODULE&)> callback)
{
    std::stack<HMODULE> modules;
    modules.push(loadedModule);

    while (modules.size())
    {
        auto module = modules.top();
        modules.pop();

        auto imageBase = (DWORD_PTR)module;

        auto header = ImageNtHeader(module);
        auto importTable = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(DWORD_PTR)(header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress + imageBase);

        while (importTable->OriginalFirstThunk)
        {
// !!!
// HERE I've got an error: importTable->Name stores 0x0000FFFF instead dll name
// !!!
            auto importedModuleName = (char*)(DWORD_PTR)(importTable->Name + imageBase);
            auto importedModule = GetModuleHandleA(importedModuleName);
            if (!importedModule)
            {
                importedModule = LoadLibraryExA(importedModuleName, 0, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);
                if (flag == FillImportFlag::Recursive)
                    modules.push(importedModule);
            }

            auto nameAddressPtr = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(DWORD_PTR)(importTable->OriginalFirstThunk + imageBase); //Import Lookup Table address (functions names)
            auto functionAddressPtr = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(DWORD_PTR)(importTable->FirstThunk + imageBase); //Import Address Table (IAT) address (functions addresses)

            while (nameAddressPtr->u1.Function)
            {
                FARPROC importedFunctionPtr = NULL;
                if (nameAddressPtr->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG)
                {
                    importedFunctionPtr = GetProcAddress(importedModule, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(nameAddressPtr->u1.Ordinal));
                }
                else
                {
                    auto impotByNameImage = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)(DWORD_PTR)(nameAddressPtr->u1.AddressOfData + imageBase);
                    importedFunctionPtr = GetProcAddress(importedModule, (char*)impotByNameImage->Name);
                }

                if (importedFunctionPtr)
                {
                    auto oldProt = 0ul;
                    VirtualProtect(functionAddressPtr, sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProt);
                    functionAddressPtr->u1.Function = (DWORD_PTR)importedFunctionPtr;
                }

                nameAddressPtr++;
                functionAddressPtr++;
            }

            importTable++;
        }

// HERE in callback I hook LoadLibrary & RegQueryVAlue calls if 'module' has such dependencies
        callback(module);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Name` field of `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` structure stores `0x0000FFFF` instead of Dll name.

So my question is how can I fix that? What does `0x0000FFFF` mean? Maybe this is some "special" module (see **api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll** below on screenshot)?

Here is screenshot from my debug session.
[image]

## UPDATE:

Maybe 0x0000FFFF means that dll doesn't have dependencies?

I've looked **api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll** dependencies in Dependency Walker and seems this dll has nothing to import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your screenshot clear view that `importTable` point to `imageBase` (i.e. `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`). this happens when `header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress == 0` - you not check for this condition, as result and error

`api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll` simply have no import - `DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT]` is zero. need check - are import exist before process it

Comment: does this mean that DLL does not have imports if and only if `DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT]` is zero? How best to check that module have no import?

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich - yes, you exactly need check `DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT]` - VirtualAddress must be !=0 and Size == `sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)*n;` where n > 0