# Set hook on LoadLibrary which was called from DllMain of hooked delayed-dll

Tags: c++, hook, dllimport, portable-executable, dllmain

My goal is hook all LoadLibrary calls from particular dll and its dependencies (which may be delayed importable). Here is how I'm trying to solve this task:

1. Load this dll using `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` flag.

   1.1. Apply this algorithm to dll's submodules recursively.
2. Fill the Import Table of this dll manually.
3. Hook all `LoadLibraryA`, `LoadLibraryW` etc. functions just patching Import Table.
4. Call `DllMain` of this dll manually with `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` flag.

And I had a problem with the last step. If I call `DllMain` manually then all inner `LoadLibrary` calls will be executed from my module's address space (not from dll's one) and all my hooks from step3 is not calling.

And I don't want to hook `LoadLibrary` calls in my main module because there is other code which calls `LoadLibrary` and I don't wont such side-effects.

So my question is how should I call DllMain in order to force it not using `LoadLibrary` from my main module? Is it because of the delayed-import? Or is it just because as I call `DllMain`? Or maybe there are better solution of this task?

Here is how I run dll:

```
void PEUtility::runDllMain(HMODULE module)
{
    typedef BOOL(WINAPI *DllMainFunPtr)(HMODULE, DWORD, LPVOID);

    auto header = ImageNtHeader(module);

    auto dllMain = (DllMainFunPtr)(header->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint + (DWORD_PTR)module);
    dllMain(module, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, NULL);
}
```

Here is how I fill Import Table: [my question about how I'm filling import table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606514/fill-in-dll-import-table-manually-image-import-descriptors-name-field-stores-0)

`LoadLibrary` hooking is similar to Import Table filling.

### UPDATE

I've added a couple of screenshots from **ApiMonitor** to demonstrate that `LoadLibrary("...mso20win32client.dll")` was called from different modules for the case then I load parent library `olmapi32.dll` (which depends on `mso20win32client.dll`) using all this stuff described above and for the case then I just call `LoadLibrary`:

When I use my method described above (using `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES`, `DllMain` etc.) (NOTE LAST LINE: `mso20win32client.dll` was loaded from `mapi32ex64.dll` - my main module):
[image: loading 'olmapi32.dll' using stuff above]

When I just call `LoadLibrary("OLMAPI32.dll")` (NOTE LAST LINE: `mso20win32client.dll` was loaded from `olmapi32.dll` - dll that I want do load using my method):
[image]

Comment: interesting how another DLL called LoadLibrary from your module. you are something confused. your way yourself load dll is incorrect. you for example not handle manifest in Dlls in this case, not create activation context. and at all, if say DLL not imported LoadLibrary, but used GetProcAddress to get this proc ? what at all you try doing ? target goal i mean. `header->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint` you also not check for 0

Comment: @RnMn, do I understand correctly that loading library using `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` and calling DllMain for particular library is not enough for manifest and context? As for `GetProcAddress` - I'm hooking `kernel32` LoadLibrary functions and I guess this library always presents in dll's Import Table. Anyway I'm hooking predefined dlls set and non of these dlls do not use `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: yes, when you use `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` dll manifest is not processing. like and tls.

Comment: and for understand what happens you need use debugger and only debugger. any apimonitor not enough

Answer (score 1):

For future readers who stumble upon this issue (and their goal is to do something between library loading and calling its init routine, for example hooking or changing some code), have a look at this answer: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6023

Basically you can hook `LdrpCallInitRoutine` in `ntdll.dll`, which is used to call the DLL entry point by the system:

```
BOOLEAN NTAPI LdrpCallInitRoutine(PDLL_INIT_ROUTINE EntryPoint, PVOID BaseAddress, ULONG Reason, PVOID Context);
```